# random but unique numbers in aix

Tags: random, numbers, unique, aix

I'm working on a script where I need a specific amount of unique numbers (this amount is given by a list of words) with constant 5 digits each number.

My first tries would be:

```
 test=`cat amount.log`

 for i in $test

       do 

           echo  $i $((RANDOM%10000+20000)) > random_numbers.log

 done
```

the output of this script is exactly the one, I am searching for:

```
word1 25439
word2 26134
word3 21741
```

But I don't trust the $random variable to give me a unique list, where I don't have a number more written than once. 
To be sure, the numbers are unique, my first attempt would be to use `sort -u` to get rid of duplicate entries, but this would mean that I have posibly less numbers then words in the list, or some words I will need to run the script again, to get a unique number for it.

I'll appreciate any suggestions, it needs to be done in unix/aix ksh shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could ensure that each number is really unique by looking for it back in the output file...

```
test=`cat amount.log`

touch random_numbers.log

for i in $test
do
        while true
        do
                num=$((RANDOM%10000+20000))
                grep $num random_numbers.log > /dev/null
                if [[ $? -gt 0 ]]
                then
                        break
                fi
        done
        echo $i $num >> random_numbers.log
done
```

Comment: I tried your answer, but grep gives me back it can't open up the file. allthough, it might worked as well, as i looked over the numbers with awk und sort -u and they seem to be unique. it could possible be just luck with this try, or is it intended that grep gives back an error message?

Comment: Probably grep complains because the file doesn't exist in the first run.  I've edited the answer.

Comment: thank you, @Roberto , that was what I was looking for. there are no duplicate entries in several tries. Just one last question, can you explain what the `if [[ $? -gt 0 ]]` does specifically? i don't understand that part.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the answers to [How to generate a list of unique random strings?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/how-to-generate-a-list-of-unique-random-strings)  One of the ideas there should help you.